# Is it possible to merge resp. simplify these two Collectors.toMap calls?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Please consider the follwing exemplifying code:

```
Function<Pair<String, String>, Integer> lengthOfKey
        = p -> p.getKey().length();

Collector<Pair<String, String>, ?, Map<String, String>>
        convertPairListToMap =
        Collectors.toMap(
            Pair<String, String>::getKey,
            Pair<String, String>::getValue);

Function<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>
        convertValueToUpperCase =
        map -> map.entrySet().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        e -> e.getValue().toUpperCase())
        );

list.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                lengthOfKey,
                collectingAndThen(
                    convertPairListToMap,
                    convertValueToUpperCase

        )))
        .forEach((keyLength, map) -> {
            // ...
        });
```

I like that by writing

```
                collectingAndThen(
                    convertPairListToMap,
                    convertValueToUpperCase
```

it is made explicit that the list of Pairs is converted to a Map and that the Values are modified. I don't want to do the uppercase conversion inside the Collector which converts the List to a Map because then this Collector would be doing more than just converting the List of Pairs to a Map as indicated by the name of the Collector. However, I don't like that in this solution the stream is collected two times - this is inefficient, isn't it? I'm therefore wondering if there is a solution to collect the stream only once, but still stating the converion to Map and the converting of the Values explictely. I searched the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) for a method to combine two `Collectors.toMap` call, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What's the problem here? Just do the uppercase in `convertPairListToMap`, and rename it to something more accurate, like `convertPairListToMapWithUppercaseValues`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I considered this, but was wondering if this is a good approach, because, as your suggested name indicates, the method would do two things at once then. I would prefer if I somehow could state these two different responsibilities explicitly like it is done with the `collectingAndThen` approach, but still keep the efficiency of collecting the stream only once.

Comment: For example, when working with streams, it's also possible to state some transforming actions in a declarative way: E.g. first do some filtering based on a predicate, then map the results. Is something similar possible in this case, too (stating the transformations I mentioned in my question explicitly and consecutively)?

Comment: How about making `convertPairListToMap` a method? Make it take 2 arguments that represent the transformation done on the keys and values respectively. You can then write `convertPairListToMap(Function.identity(), String::toUpperCase)`.

Comment: Thank you! I think it's still not ideal as the method name does not fully reveal what the method does, but the function arguments indicate now that something more is happening. I'm going with this approach for now. Thanks!

Comment: I had to undo all your verbosity and inline the variables, to eventually understand what the code is doing. When I see `list.stream() .collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getKey().length(), toMap(Pair::getKey, e -> e.getValue().toUpperCase()))) .forEach(…)`, I understand what the code is doing. I don’t need a variable named “convertValueToUpperCase” (buried somewhere between the generic type declarations), to understand that `getValue().toUpperCase()` is converting the value to uppercase; that’s what the code is already telling me. You are completely running into the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you could simplify and share the problem you are attempting to solve with the implementation shared, you would most likely have a better and easier solution.

For what it seems like, the following should do what you are looking for (barring the `merging`)

```
Function<Pair<String, String>, Integer> lengthOfKey
        = p -> p.getKey().length();
Collector<Pair<String, String>, ?,
        Map<String, String>> convertToValueMapWithUpperCase =
        Collectors.toMap(Pair<String, String>::getValue,
                e -> e.getValue().toUpperCase());

Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> groupingAndTransformation = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(lengthOfKey,
                convertToValueMapWithUpperCase));
```

The result of the following when executed for the sample

```
List<Pair<String, String>> list = List.of(
        new Pair("naman", "stackoverflow"),
        new Pair("daniel", "dubov"),
        new Pair("vishy", "anand"),
        new Pair("user", "sample"),
        new Pair("comments", "section"));
```

is the same as the code shared by you(when printed):

```
{4={sample=SAMPLE}, 5={anand=ANAND, stackoverflow=STACKOVERFLOW}, 6={dubov=DUBOV}, 8={section=SECTION}}
```